# How to generate a random sequence with step +/-5

Tags: python

I want to generate a sequence, starting at a random value, with following values being either +5 or -5 from the previous value.

I tried this:

```
result = random.randrange(8, 50, 5)
```

But it always adds +5 to the previous value.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Pick a random starting number, then add 5 every time you want another number.

Comment: You want to do this forever, or is there any termination condition, or max/min threshold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick a random starting number. Then randomly choose `+5` or `-5` to add to it when you want the next number.

```
result = random.randint(1, 100)
print(result)
while True:
    result += random.choice((5, -5))
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is obvious.

```
result = random.randrange(2,10) * 5
```

Comment: Isn't this practically the same as the code in the question?

Comment: i edited the question, i need +5 or -5 from the last number

Comment: That's not at all random though.

Comment: Outcome +5 or -5 is determined by random

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, duh, I didn't pay attention.  I'll leave the answer since it has useful follow-up.